# Book recommendations for Binary Integer Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

I'm looking for a book on BILP, which focuses on algorithms / solutions methods. So far, I only found the following books on ILP

1. "Integer and combinatorial optimization" by Nemhauser, George L.
2. "Integer programming" by Wolsey, Laurence A.
3. "Introduction to Linear Optimization" by Bertsemas, Dimitris
4. "Theory of Linear and Integer Programming" by Schrijver, Alexander

Where, at least for me with a little background in (convex) optimization, the last book is really 'hardcore'

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer to your question is none. The closest you can find is probably going to be a book on combinatorial optimization, because in general problems with only binary variables tend to be combinatorial. I would suggest [Cook et al.](http://books.google.com/books?id=tarLTNwM3gEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=combinatorial%20optimization&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RVTAU73BLYiTyAS0yYKoBA&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=combinatorial%20optimization&f=false) as a good starting point. [Korte and Vygen](http://books.google.com/books?id=8535vmYbLGYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=combinatorial%20optimization%20korte%20vygen&hl=en&sa=X&ei=plTAU-beLIqSyATrl4Io&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA) is also a great reference.

May I ask why you're interested in binary ILPs? If there's a specific problem you're trying to solve, or a specific question you're trying to answer, that might make it easier to point you in the right direction.